# Cosuming JSON with JavaScriptSerializer returns NULL object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, null, javascriptserializer

My Json string:

```
    jsonString ="{"GetStatusResult":[{"CaseCompleteInd":"N","CaseNbr":"999999","InSurgeryNowInd":"Y","InRoomNowInd":"N"}]}";
```

My classes:

```
public class GetStatusResult
{
    public List<CaseModel> caseDetails { get; set; }
}

public class CaseModel
{
    public string CaseCompleteInd { get; set; }
    public string CaseConfirmNbr { get; set; }

    public string InSurgeryNowInd { get; set; }
    public string InRoomNowInd{ get; set; }
}
```

}

My code:

```
    GetStatusResult caseInfo = new GetStatusResult();

    JavaScriptSerializer jsSerializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    caseInfo = jsSerializer.Deserialize<GetStatusResult>(jsonString);
```

My Problem:

The object is always returning as NULL and the CaseModel details are not being populated.  The JSON string obviously has data, but I feel that my class structure is somehow messed up with the root level class.  It appears similar to other examples posted here and elsewhere, so I'm at a loss right now.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I presume you mean the `caseInfo` object is returning null?  Where are you referencing the `CaseModel` class?  I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you modify your JSON string to

```
jsonString ="{"caseDetails":[{"CaseCompleteInd":"N","CaseNbr":"999999","InSurgeryNowInd":"Y","InRoomNowInd":"N"}]}";
```

then it should work.

Properties of JSON object correspond to the properties of .NET object having the same name.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.  I was not aware the naming had to be the same.